# PHP Delete event ID

Tags: php, mysql

I have made an Event calender but now I'm facing a problem when the user deletes a event.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBLJ9.png

```
<h2>Date <?php echo "$day"."/"."$month"."/"."$year"."<br>"; ?></h2>
<?php

// event weer gegeven
while ($events = mysql_fetch_array($resultEvents)){
echo "<strong>Event ID:</strong> ".$events['id']."<br>";
echo "Added: ".$events['added']."<br>";
echo "Title: ".$events['titel']."<br>";
echo "Detail: ".$events['content']."<br>";
?>

<form method="POST" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<input type="submit" name="delete"  value="Delete"><br >
<input type="submit" name="edit"  value="Edit"><br >
</form>
<?php 

 if(isset($_POST['delete'])){

 $user  = $_POST['delete'];
$delet_query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM kalender_contents WHERE `id` = '$events'")     or     die(mysql_error());

if($delet_query) {
echo "event deleted";
echo $events;
            }
            }    
    }
}
}
?>
```

But the `WHERE`id`= '$events'` does not work. How can I specify the ID on the button click.

Comment: Use $events['id'], also put your if(isset($_POST['delete'])){ on top

Comment: Inevitably someone will mention this, so it may as well be me. Don't use `mysql_*` functions http://bit.ly/phpmsql - use mysqli or pdo instead. (this does not answer the question, you just shouldn't use them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put its relevant `event id` into the form like

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="event_id" id="event_id" value="<?php echo $events['id'];?>">
    <input type="submit" name="delete"  value="Delete"><br >
    <input type="submit" name="edit"  value="Edit"><br >
</form>
```

And in your submit query use like

```
$delet_query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM kalender_contents 
                            WHERE `id` = $_POST['event_id']");
```

Whenever you are submitting the form then its event id will be passed and you need to pass that post variable to your delete query.

Further you need to escape the id to prevent the `sql injection` with `mysql_real_escape_string` at your query like

```
$delet_query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM kalender_contents 
                            WHERE `id` = ".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['event_id']));
```

Comment: This code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Don't forget to sanitize `$_POST['event_id']` value. You can parse it to integer or add quotes around the value and escape it using `addslashes` or `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: Thanku @GuilhermeSehn but it is hidden field right so there is no way for the SQL injection.Anyway thanks for the suggestion.I have added it for my ans

Comment: @Gautam3164 even if hidden, it is very easy to modify its value with a simple DOM inspector!

Comment: Of course there is a way to do SQL injection easily in this case by changing its value with the browser developer tools. Do not ever trust your client side inputs.

Comment: Ok I will obey with you all.Thanku.

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but your modified query gives an error: unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Comment: Sorry it is an typo.Now U can try it

Comment: Your code is still vunerable as it is missing quotes around your value in the SQL query.

Comment: Since it is an id value no need to put that in quotes

Comment: @Gautam3164 Of course you need quotes! Either escape the string and treat it as a string (incl. using quotes) or convert it to integer.

Answer (score 0):

Create a hidden field with value of event id.

```
<h2>Date <?php echo "$day"."/"."$month"."/"."$year"."<br>"; ?></h2>
<?php

// event weer gegeven
while ($events = mysql_fetch_array($resultEvents)){
echo "<strong>Event ID:</strong> ".$events['id']."<br>";
echo "Added: ".$events['added']."<br>";
echo "Title: ".$events['titel']."<br>";
echo "Detail: ".$events['content']."<br>";
?>


<form method="POST" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="event_id" value="<?php echo $events['id'];?>">
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete"><br >
<input type="submit" name="edit" value="Edit"><br >
</form>
<?php 

 if(isset($_POST['delete'])){


 $user  = $_POST['delete'];
$delet_query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM kalender_contents WHERE `id` = '$events'")     or     die(mysql_error());

if($delet_query) {
echo "event deleted";
echo $events;
            }
            }    
    }
}
}
?>
```